# ValueError: too many values to unpack python error

Tags: python, list

I have this python list `lst4` which when printed to logger using `logger.debug` looks like this-

```
["('08AM', '02-19')", "('14PM', '2204')", "('14PM', '3201')"]
```

Now when I do

```
innr_lst = ["{Start Time: %s, Room Number: %s}" % (starttime, room_number)
            for starttime, room_number in lst4]
```

I get this error:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack

`lst4` (end of the list comprehension above) comes from a database `select`:

```
def ret():
    SELECT Start_Time,Room_Number...

    for i in resultSet1:
        time = i[0]
        rec = ((time).strftime('%H%p'), i[1])
        lst4.append(str(rec))

    return lst4

def main_func():

    lst4 = ret()
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Do you have to store these values as a string? I mean, you can store `"('08AM', '02-19')"` as `('08AM', '02-19')` - without quotes.

Comment: You don't have a list of pairs, you have a list of _strings_. Presumably you want the inner values of the tuples described by those strings (e.g. `'08AM'` and `'02-19'`). Where did you get these values from? The best solution is to fix them at the source.

Comment: Members of the `lst4` list are strings, not tuples. Notice the quotes. The "too many values" are the characters in each string.

Comment: @Chris the values are coming from a select statement result from database.

Comment: @Chris I added some more info in my post about from where last4 is coming

Comment: after your edit, delete the str() in the line `lst4.append(str(rec))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each element of lst4 is a single value: a string, such as

```
"('08AM', '02-19')"
```

This *resembles* a tuple of strings, but it's not: it's a single string that happens to contain characters including parentheses and single quotation marks.  As a consequence, you don't have two values to extract with `starttime, roomnumber`.

To fix this, remove the double quotation marks from the values.  This will leave you with a list of tuples.  If you do not have that level of control, then you'll have to parse each string into its component values: try using a regular expression, or simply split the string at the comma and re-form the tuple from the two pieces.

Comment: I added some more info in my post about from where last4 is coming

Comment: See the comment from @PRMoureau: drop that `str` operation in your `append` command.

Answer (score 0):

As prune said, lst4 should contain tuples of strings, not strings that look like tuples of strings. For example,

```
[("08AM", "02-19"), ("14PM", "2204")]
```

With that said, inner_lst should probably also be a list of tuples of strings. This means the string formatting for the two strings in the tuple needs to be done separately.

```
innr_lst = [("Start Time: %s" % starttime, "Room Number: %s" % room_number)
        for starttime, room_number in lst4]
```